# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'predictions' is undefined

Tags: flask

I have a flask website. I was to make prediction images using the model that I build in Google Collab. In this, I have 25 classes and I took 3 classes for testing its work or not. I have already run it but when I go to the predict pages it seems to get the error '**jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'predictions' is undefined**' Can anyone help me. Thank u

The Python Code:

```
with open('CNN.pth','rb') as file:
    model=torch.load('CNN.pth',map_location='cpu')

classes=['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24']

def predict(filename,model):
    img=load_img(filename,target_size=(32,32))
    img=img_to_array(img)
    img=img.reshape(1,32,32,3)

    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img/255.0
    result = model.predict(img)

    dict_result = {}
    for i in range(25):
        dict_result[result[0][i]] = classes[i]

    res = result[0]
    res.sort()
    res = res[::-1]
    prob = res[:3]

    prob_result = []
    class_result = []
    for i in range(3):
        prob_result.append((prob[i]*100).round(2))
        class_result.append(dict_result[prob[i]])

    return class_result , prob_result

@app.route('/predict' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def success():
    error = ''
    target_img = os.path.join(os.getcwd() , 'static/images')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.files):
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                file.save(os.path.join(target_img , file.filename))
                img_path = os.path.join(target_img , file.filename)
                img = file.filename

                class_result , prob_result = predict(img_path , model)

                predictions = {
                      "class1":class_result[0],
                        "class2":class_result[1],
                        "class3":class_result[2],
                        "prob1": prob_result[0],
                        "prob2": prob_result[1],
                        "prob3": prob_result[2],
                }

            else:
                error = "Please upload images of jpg , jpeg and png extension only"

            if(len(error) == 0):
                return  render_template('predict.html' , img  = img , predictions = predictions)
            else:
                return render_template('home.html' , error = error)

    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
```

Index.html

```
<tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Probability</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>{{predictions.class1}}</th>
                <th>{{predictions.prob1}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>{{predictions.class2}}</th>
                <th>{{predictions.prob2}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>{{predictions.class3}}</th>
                <th>{{predictions.prob3}}</th>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put an if - else condition, if you pay attention, the values ​​rendered in the if block and the rendered values ​​in the else block are different.

But all the values ​​are used in the html file.

If your code run else block so:

```
            else:
            return render_template('home.html' , error = error)
```

-> Where is the "prediction" value?

How can html predict a value that is not rendered as a value?

If you want to use like that:

```
    @app.route('/predict' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
    def success():
    predictions = dict() # if predictions is not empty ok, else doens't matter
    error = ''
    target_img = os.path.join(os.getcwd() , 'static/images')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.files):
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                file.save(os.path.join(target_img , file.filename))
                img_path = os.path.join(target_img , file.filename)
                img = file.filename

            class_result , prob_result = predict(img_path , model)

            predictions = {
                  "class1":class_result[0],
                    "class2":class_result[1],
                    "class3":class_result[2],
                    "prob1": prob_result[0],
                    "prob2": prob_result[1],
                    "prob3": prob_result[2],
            }

        else:
            error = "Please upload images of jpg , jpeg and png extension only"

        if(len(error) == 0):
            return  render_template('predict.html' , img  = img , predictions = predictions)
        else:
            return render_template('home.html' , error = error, predictions = predictions)

else:
    return render_template('home.html', predictions = predictions)
```

And you can use jinja condition like that:

```
{% if predictions|length > 0 %}

 <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Probability</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>{{predictions.class1}}</th>
            <th>{{predictions.prob1}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>{{predictions.class2}}</th>
            <th>{{predictions.prob2}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>{{predictions.class3}}</th>
            <th>{{predictions.prob3}}</th>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If my prediction and class is empty, what is problem?

Comment: If your prdeiction values is none or zero so empy, jinja will not display anything in your template. You can use this : {% if predictions|length > 0 %} <tr> ... {% else %} <p> Prediction is None {% endif %}.   Also you can use control for  this code : class_result , prob_result = predict(img_path , model) , if class_result is not None and prob_result is not None: ..

Comment: I am already using the code that you have given to me but the answer is always none. Is my model wrong?

Comment: with open('CNN.pth','rb') as file:
    model=torch.load('CNN.pth',map_location='cpu') , you opened your cnn.pth as file named file but you did not use file variable there. I think your problem is this.  Or your model can be wrong. I can't make an exact guess from this code block.

Comment: Is it wrong with my code. Can you check my code in link https://ibb.co/dP0LLq1.

Comment: I was input the code before the @app.route that I post in the question

Comment: If you use try-exception instead of giving a string value to the error variable, you can see what caused the error when you get an error. I can't see a syntax error in your code right now. Your model may not be able to predict and return null. This can affect your dataset and the algorithm you use. Other than that, I don't think there is a bug with the flask. I think you should debug. so you can see on which line you didn't get the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

in the last line of code written in python

```
return render_template('home.html')
```

you don't specify the predictions variable, unlike you did previously

```
return  render_template('predict.html' , img  = img , predictions = predictions)
```